# Winscp batch file will not run from scheduler

Tags: ssis, sftp

I created a batch file to download a file from a client.  I am running windows server 2012.  I am using a execute process task in ssis 2014.  Both the batch file and my package run fine manually. When I run via the ssis scheduler it gets the following error:  Exeute Process Task Error- In Executing C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe""/C E:\Scripts\Nationwidebatch.bat"at"". the process code was "1" while expected was "0".

```
 @echo off
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
 /log="C:\Users\jfrench\AppData\Local\Temp\4\!S.log" /ini=nul ^
 /command ^
"open sftp://ecafxxxx:xxxxxxx@tower.nationwide.com/ 
-hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 a6:e9:1a:b0:0d:09:0f:2d:2b:92:82:00:d3:87:9b:36""" ^
"cd /FromNationwide/icafarmb" ^
"option transfer ascii" ^
"get allied.txt  \\CFBF-SQL\Insurance\Download\AlliedNW\" ^
"exit"

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
echo Success
) else (
echo Error
)
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%
```

I have run it manually from a batch file, manually from visual studio , and manually from ssis catalog db and they all run successfully. As soon as you add it to the scheduler it dies.

Comment: To get some further details about the error, configure the execute process task to have the error output to a variable.  Then write the variable to the log.  Also, what is SSIS Scheduler?  Do you mean SQL Agent?

Comment: Your batch file is syntactically wrong. It cannot work. Or did you just break it when posting here? Make sure you post it literally. + Show us the WinSCP log file!

Comment: I  do mean the SQL Agent.  The code above runs fine until I assign it to the scheduler.  What is wrong with my syntext for it is running fine?

Comment: I got updated error information

Comment: Message
      The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local         Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
    {806835AE-FD04-4870-A1E8-D65535358293}
 and APPID 
{EE4171E6-C37E-4D04-AF4C-8617BC7D4914}
 to the user NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT SID (S-1-5-80-344959196-2060754871-2302487193-2804545603-1466107430) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: Do you use the same "User" to run the SQL Agent and when you run it manually? it might be a permissions issue.